# HTTP 200 None Message (Google Appengine) - Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, http, python-requests

I want to write a bot to send Images from a url to a chat program called Telegram.

Whenever I request an Image, I get nothing but this Message in the Log file:

```
15:06:55.705 Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdn-images-1.medium.
15:06:55.734 "GET /max/768/1*sPf7izMPYM76LB_xKb0bzw.png HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

I want to use [This Image](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/768/1*sPf7izMPYM76LB_xKb0bzw.png)

What really desturbs me is the code 200, which should mean it's ok. But the 'None' afterwarts is kinda shady.

The Code I use is:

```
        import requests
```

---

```
        def sendImageFromUrl(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        output = StringIO(response.content)
        img = Image.open(output)
        img.save(output, 'JPEG')
        resp = multipart.post_multipart(BASE_URL + 'sendPhoto', [
            ('chat_id', str(chat_id)),
            ('caption', 'My Caption'),
        ], [
            ('photo', 'image.jpg', output.getvalue()),
        ])
```

and the request / call

```
sendImageFromUrl("http://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/768/1*sPf7izMPYM76LB_xKb0bzw.png")
```

Anyone know what the Problem is?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the GET request to return?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm hoping to get my Image sent

Comment: You're making a GET request, so you're not sending anything. What do you expect that request to return?

Comment: I use GET to get the Content of the URL (picture) in bytes. And with StringIO, it reads those bytes as a file.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how App Engine logs HTTP requests using their URLFetch backend. My app does it for `GET` and `POST` requests

```
2015-09-09 16:30:26.932 "GET /webservice/restful/server.php/syllabus?id=437 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2015-09-09 16:30:27.273 "POST /api/event HTTP/1.1" 200 None`
```

Comment: So what your saying is that it's going ok and works fine?
I must be missing something in my code then... thanks

Comment: Correct. The built in logging urlfetch does this. I don't know where the `None` comes from but it is normal.